# SonarQube: Multiple gating criteria on a github PR

Tags: sonarqube

We are using sonarqube with github code actions.

We run two type of tests (Unit Test, E2E Test) in each of our PR. Now we are using [sonarqube github integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.8/devops-platform-integration/github-integration/) to have a quality gate rule of minimum 80% coverage from Unit Test.

But we are not able to use jacoco coverage report generated from E2E test in our quality gate. Can someone let me know if it is possible to add coverage criteria from E2E tests also. For example we want to have rule like 80% coverage from Unit test and 70% coverage from E2E test before a PR passes the quality gate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in [sonarqube community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/multiple-gating-criteria-on-a-github-pr/94596/2) that it is not possible to do.

```
Hi,

There’s no differentiation of test type in SonarQube, and I’m not aware of a workaround to accomplish what you’re after.

 
Ann
```